# Hide all div of particular class except one using CSS only

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have below HTML and I want to hide all divs having class 'msg' excluding one div having same class.

```
<html>

<div class="ref" >
    <div class="msg">  Message ref </div>
</div>

<div class="msg">  Message 1 </div>
<div class="msg">  Message 2 </div>
<div class="msg">  Message 3 </div>

</html>
```

Here I want to hide all div having class 'msg' except div which is inside another div having class 'ref' using css only.

My style for that is

```
.msg:not(.ref.msg) {
     display: none;
}
```

But it is not working.Please suggest me some required tweaks to my CSS style to achieve result.

Thanks.

Comment: .ref .msg add a space between both the classes, your code states that div with the class of ref & msg together. hence insert a space between .ref .msg

Comment: I suspect this is not possible as there is no parent selector which I think is required here as `:not` only accepts simple selectors.

Comment: @WisdmLabs still not working after adding space between classes

Comment: @Paulie_D Suggest the way round

Comment: There is no single selector that can do this...see the answers below.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this

```
<style>
    .msg{
     display: none;
    }
    .ref .msg{
     display: block;
    }

</style>
```

Edit Note:
If you want to apply the 'not'rule I think you would need this structure

```
<style>
    div:not(.ref){display: none;}
</style>
<div class="msg ref">  Message ref </div>
<div class="msg">  Message 1 </div>
<div class="msg">  Message 2 </div>
<div class="msg">  Message 3 </div>`
```

Comment: No doubt,It's working But Could we do it in single styling?

Comment: I think that having you're structure if code is quiet difficult to do it in a single styling rule, note that you have you're "ref" class div inside another div what means that you're working in differents levels. You will need the code that I add on the edit note to apply the 'not' rule

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code:

**CSS**

```
.ref :not(.msg) {
    display: none;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="ref" >
    <div class="msg">  Message ref 1 </div>
</div>
<div class="ref" >
    <div class="msg1">  Message ref 2 </div>
</div>
<div class="msg">  Message 1 </div>
<div class="msg">  Message 2 </div>
<div class="msg">  Message 3 </div>
```

make sure you add a space after .ref class.

Answer (score 1):

```
.msg { display:none; }

.ref .msg { display:block; }
```

This should be working.